# How can I extract the url from a link following an italicized element with xpath?

Tags: html, xpath

I'm trying to extract a link from a lot of pages with xpath and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. The pages are poorly formatted with italicizing which is what I think is throwing it off.

This is an example of the way the html is formatted:

```
<p>
    <i>This content is constant</i>
    <a href="example.com/exampe123">
        <i>This text changes</i>
    </a>
    <i> </i>
</p>
```

In this example, the word "text" doesn't change but the rest of the words do.

I tried using the following xpath but it didn't work:

```
//p/a[contains(text(), 'text')]/@href
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use one of below `XPath` expressions:

```
//p/a[i[contains(text(), 'text')]]/@href

//p/a[contains(., 'text')]/@href
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `<i>` elements are causing issues, or if they are mal-formed, how about just textually removing ALL `<i>` and `</i>` strings before creating your XPath object?

```
var cleanString = dirtyString.Replace("<i>","").Replace("</i>","");
```

And then create your XPath object from that "clean" string. Chances are, you don't need to know where `<i>` segments are in your app.